# Space between horizontal lines in awesomebox

Tags: parameters

I need a small space between top & bottom of the paragraph

#### MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{awesomebox}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\aweboxsignraise}{-10mm}
\awesomebox[white][\abShortLine]{2pt}{\faGrinBeam}{red}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package implements `\awesomebox` as a `tabular` and the rules are produced by `\cline`.

Here's a workaround that allows adding vertical space of a specified dimension.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{awesomebox}

\newcommand{\abovespace}[1]{\hrule width 0pt height #1\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\belowspace}[1]{\par\hrule width 0pt height #1\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\aweboxsignraise}{-10mm}
\awesomebox[white][\abShortLine]{2pt}{\faGrinBeam}{red}{
  \abovespace{6pt}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
  aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
  esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
  occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
  deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  \belowspace{6pt}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]